# Switching a DbContext to using Ninject Dependency injection per user session

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject, dbcontext, ninject.web.mvc

I have an application that is used in 2 different sites. Each site has it's own Database.

There are 2 DbContexts, 1 for each site. When the user opens my application there is a splash page where they choose their site. After choosing the site the kernel is rebound to use the DbContext for the selected site.

```
private void RebindDbContext(string site)
{
    switch (site)
    {
        case "Site1":
            _kernel.Rebind<DbContext>().To<DbContext1>().InRequestScope();
            break;
        case "Site2":
            _kernel.Rebind<DbContext>().To<DbContext2>().InRequestScope();
            break;
    }
}
```

**Now for the Bob & Mary explanation:**
This works fine when Bob selects site 1. But when Mary selects a site 2. The dbContext for Bob is re-bound to site 2. What I want is for Bob and Mary to be able to use the application at the same time without affecting each other.

I have tried using TransientScope, ThreadScope and InRequest Scope but none of these have worked.

The application is being run on an IIS server

Thanks for any help

Comment: How about using ninject provider for this purpose? Or bind to method instead of rebind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bindings are intended to be done once per application, not dependent upon state. In this instance, you have a couple options:

**1) A `Ninject.Activation.IProvider`**

```
public class DbContextProvider : Ninject.Activation.IProvider
{
    public Type Type
    {
        get { return typeof(DbContext); }
    }

    public object Create(IContext context)
    {
        var siteProvider = context.Kernel.Get<ISiteProvider>(); // use a provider to find which site is being used
        switch (siteProvider.Current)
        {
            case "Site1":
                return new DbContext1(); // or use a factory to create
            case "Site2":
                return new DbContext2();
        }
    }
}
```

then:

```
Bind<DbContext>().ToProvider<DbContextProvider>().InRequestScope();
```

**2) Conditional Binding**

The `When()` modifier has a bunch of overloads for different states, or you could create an extension method if you have one type you use a lot.

```
        Bind<DbContext>().To<DbContext1>()
            .When(request => request.ParentContext.Kernel.Get<ISiteProvider>().Current == "Site1")
            .InRequestScope();

        Bind<DbContext>().To<DbContext2>()
            .When(request => request.ParentContext.Kernel.Get<ISiteProvider>().Current == "Site2")
            .InRequestScope();
```

This is a good option if you only have a few conditions that this binding may be applied. If your logic gets ANY more complex than this, go for the provider. Also note that Conditional Bindings incur a performance penalty.

**3) A `ToMethod()` Binding**

For the simplest binding logic, you can have Ninject run some code each time the binding is resolved:

```
Bind<DbContext>().ToMethod(context =>
            context.Kernel.Get<ISiteProvider>().GetSite());
```

Basically, which option you select depends on how much logic is involved in deciding which instance to activate. In each instance, you can either `new()` up an instance, or you have access to the IKernel in which you can resolve an instance:

```
context.Kernel.Get<DbContext2>();
```

here's some official documentation of the activation process:

https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Providers%2C-Factory-Methods-and-the-Activation-Context